# Remove accent in search term Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I just want to know how to remove any accents (and where) on my search term before doing my query.

I use Django 1.9.

```
search_fields = ('name', )
filter_backends = (OrderingFilter, SearchFilter)
ordering = ('name', )
```

My serializer :

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
another = AnotherSerializer()

class Meta:
    model = My_model
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'position')
```

My model :

```
class My_model(models.Model):

class Meta:
    ordering = ['index']

name = models.CharField(max_length=250, verbose_name=_("My_model name"))
another = models.ForeignKey(Another, verbose_name=_("Another"))

@staticmethod
def autocomplete_search_fields():
    return ("id__icontains", "name__icontains", "another__address__icontains")

def __unicode__(self):
    return "%s %s : %s - %s" % (_("My_model"), self.pk, self.name, self.address)
```

Comment: Do you mean Djago 1.9?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own CustomisedSearchFilter which inherit from SearchFilter, and overwrite the get_search_terms() methods to do anything you like, remove accents etc. here, the following codes is just the original codes of SearchFilter:

```
class SearchFilter(BaseFilterBackend):

    def get_search_terms(self, request):
        """
        Search terms are set by a ?search=... query parameter,
        and may be comma and/or whitespace delimited.
        """
        params = request.query_params.get(self.search_param, '')
        return params.replace(',', ' ').split()
```

and your codes should looks like:

```
class CustomisedSearchFilter(SearchFilter):

    def get_search_terms(self, request):
        params = request.query_params.get(self.search_param, '')
        terms = params.replace(',', ' ').split()
        # do whatever you want about the terms
        # ...
        import unidecode
        terms = [unidecode.unidecode(term) for term in terms]

        return terms
```

Comment: maybe check the offical docs: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/

Comment: Importing unidecode inside the `get_search_terms` might degrade performance as it will be imported each time the filter is used.

Answer (score 1):

There is package called [unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode). It might be helpful.

Example:

```
In [1]: import unidecode

In [2]: unidecode.unidecode('Aąśðśæð')
Out[2]: 'Aasdsaed'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation. It's better because it is called the super()

```py
import unidecode


class SearchAccentFilter(SearchFilter):
    def get_search_terms(self, request):
        terms = super().get_search_terms(request)
        terms = [unidecode.unidecode(term) for term in terms]

        return terms
```